# JavaScript action from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Someone can explain the difference between

```
$(data.selector)[data.action]
```

and :

```
$(data.selector).data.action
```

data.selector and data.action are two string

Comment: In the first snippet `data.action` needs to be a string or number, in the second snippet it can be anything

Comment: @Teemu: There's absolutely no relation between the `data.action` in both examples, aside from them being written using the same letters.

Comment: @Cerbrus Did I say there should?

Comment: Kinda, you implied that in the second snippet, `data.action` is something. It's not. `data.action` on its own there should throw an error.

Comment: Why there should be an error? It's just an expression, like a lonely number on a line, the return value is just not  used anywhere. Like I said (or rather you did), it has to refer something, if it doesn't, then an error occurs.